# Why does a file's movement cause all of its lines to be removed and then added?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I tried moving a file into a subfolder, and git sees that it has been just "renamed"... but also sees that **its whole content got removed and then added.**

For some reason with some files I could move them without losing all of their lines' actual/correct/original `git blame`. But with some, I can't.

I'm on **Windows** and using **SourceTree**. It seems like that maybe it's not git's fault but SourceTree's?

I tried it on my **other computer**, using Windows 10 and SourceTree as well, and **everything works there**. I could move around everything everywhere without triggering changes, affecting git blames, etc.

Any recommendations? I guess commiting file movements with CLI would be the go-to, but I'm using SourceTree to avoid that. :\

[image]
Anyway if there is no other solution, could you recommend a quick command to easily & safely commit a whole folder's and its subfolders' movement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's the same thing regardless of front-end you are using. Git **does not** save any information regarding renaming of a file because it saves _the whole snapshot_ of the project every commit. So, when checking differences between commits, it has to look at files that are present, added/removed to be able to _infer_ that a file has been moved (and then there are configurable thresholds to match for that detection to work)... same thing that happens when there is a merge, for example.

Comment: If it's the same thing then why does one movement changes the file in no way while other file marks all lines as changed? With one file movement SourceTree says "no change", and all lines' keep their previous blame from i.e. X months ago... With another one all lines will point to the file movement commet. :|

Comment: This looks like you changed whitespace (CRLF endings).

Comment: @torek According to VS Code & Notepad++ the files are CRLF and they stay that way even after moving. (While in SourceTree it says that the whole content got changed)

Comment: It looks like SourceTree is just struggling to show the state clearly. It's showing the old path as staged, and attributing the new path's lines to that as well. Assuming that git is already doing the right thing and SourceTree just displays it badly, do you still have a question?

Comment: No, git commit does the same thing, even though git diff returns nothing. The main point of the question is why is it working with some files, but not with others.

Comment: "I tried it on my other computer, using Windows 10 and SourceTree as well, and everything works there.": can you compare your `git config --global -l` as well as your Git version between the two computers? For instance, any `core.autocrlf` set in one to `false`, and not in the other?

Comment: What does the diff look like *after* you've committed? Git doesn't trace file renames, it calculates the likeliness a file was either renamed or moved. This sometimes causes funny behavior.

Comment: Are you using *just* sourcetree, or also edit in an IDE? Use WSL? In explorer? In gitbash or cmd or powershell? Do you have any hooks in your project? Are there any global git settings in place like autocrlf or global .gitattributes?

Comment: @jessehouwing I only have LFS stuff in .gitattributes. I edit in VS code, move the files in Unity so meta files will easily follow, and I only use git through SourceTree. autocrlf is false on the working computer, I'll have to get home to check the other one. But as far as I remember, I already checked it and on the other machine both "working and not-working files" (before any change) are  all CRLF.

Comment: @VonC Yes, at the working machine autocrlf is set to false, while on the other, there is no such config in the global config

Comment: Then try and set it to false, then try a move again.

Comment: @VonC Now it works with the files which previously didn't work and doesn't work with ones that worked.

Comment: Have you tried just making the commit and afterwards look at what sourcetree says about that commit? You can always return to the previous commit latter ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kim Yes, I did and it messed up all the lines' git blame, that why I had to revert to previous commit and decided to ask for a fix here :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things to understand here.

First, Git knows nothing about "what changed". Git traffics entirely in commits. A commit is not a change or a difference; it is a snapshot of the entire state of your project. Thus, if you make a commit, and then move a file and add everything and commit again, all you have is one commit that contains file A (but not file B) and another commit that contains file B (but not file A). In other words, Git is completely neutral as to "what happened"; that is something that *humans* like to think about, but it is no business of Git's. Git just knows that there was one state of things and then there was another state of things. As King Lear says, "Look on this picture and on this."

But second, Git also tries to be *kind* to humans by giving *information* about what changed, even though it doesn't actually know anything about the matter. When you ask for a diff, whether that be through `git show` or `git log` or `git diff` or whatever, Git tries to do exactly what a human being would do: it looks at the first commit and looks at the second commit, and tries to "spot the difference" between them. The conclusions that it comes to are not in any way baked into the repository; the repository contains nothing but commits. These conclusions about what the difference is are *ephemeral* — Git is trying figure out *right now* how these commits differ, purely for the purposes of showing the difference to you.

(The exception to this rule is what happens when Git performs a merge. A merge is a situation where Git calculates a diff and actually *uses* it to generate a completely new commit. All commands that use merge logic — `git merge`, `git cherry-pick`, `git rebase` — operate this way.)

---

So now, with the basics out of the way, let's talk about how Git displays the difference between two commits to *you*, the human. If you make a commit, and then move a file and add everything and commit, as far as Git is concerned the only thing that happened is that one file vanished (was deleted) and another file appeared (was created). That is, as it were, its fallback position: "That's my story and I'm sticking to it." And you have to admit that this is a good rock-bottom description of what happened.

But Git has in fact heard of the concept of file renaming, and it knows that when it displays a diff or a history, knowing about file renaming might be useful. So when a file disappears and another appears, Git also compares the files and tries to decide whether they might in fact be, in terms of their *content*, the "same" file. If all you did between commits was move one file, without doing anything else at all, Git is very very likely to conclude that the file was renamed. And that's nice, because if you ask to do a `git log` where you are tracing the history of a file back through time (i.e. `git log --follow`), Git can then display the history before the move and the history after the move as a single history. (Remember, Git does not *know* anything about history; this is purely a *display* convenience to help you, the human.)

But that — and this is is my point — is as far as it goes. Git is just a machine, and "very very likely" is no more than it says. Whether Git *will* in fact see a particular diff between two commits as involving a file renaming is something of a crapshoot. *There is uncertainty here* as to how Git will behave. In fact, you can try to *affect* the way Git thinks about this;  see the `-B` and `-M` options of `git log`, where you get to say how similar two files need to be to be considered the same file.

Moreover, you are *not* using Git directly; you are using a GUI. So you are reliant on that GUI for two things that you do not control: what the GUI *says* to Git, and how the GUI *displays* what Git says to the GUI. Those things are uncertain too.

So with all these layers of uncertainty, both the uncertainty as to how Git will understand the history and the extra layers of uncertainty added by the use of the GUI, it is not surprising if sometimes the GUI shows a file rename as purely "one file vanished and another file appeared" — because that, after all, is the rock bottom truth of the matter.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But there must be some logic behind the behaviours if on one machine (Win10 + Source Tree) some renames behave like I want them to behave and some don't.... while on another machine, all files always behave like I want them to behave.

Comment: Is it possible to change the threshold that Git uses to detect similarity between 2 files to judge whether a difference is a rename?